# Reason for the appropriateness of the z-test for linear regression slope check

Tags: regression, z-test

I know that the z-test can be used to compare the slopes of two regression lines (lines fitted to two separate data sets).

What I do not understand is WHY we can use the z-test for that? Therefore I am really interested in:

**1. What is the (statistical) reason that the z-test can be used to check the slopes? So WHY can we use the z-test to check the slopes and what is the z-test doing to return a result?**

**2. What if there are more than 2 regression lines?**

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: It's not clear what sort of explanation you're seeking for "the concept behind the z-test". What is it you want to know?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. I want to know 1. WHY we can use the z-test to check the slopes of two regression lines. 2. How this is working in practice --> If possible with an example

Comment: That's more concrete, thanks. Could you edit to clarify your question along those lines please?

Comment: Sry I do not have those lines, since the example is from a textbook where the data is not given... it is kind of "we compute the regression lines for DatA with... and DatB with ... "

Comment: You misunderstand me. I mean please edit [something similar](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/along+those+lines) to the clarification you have in comments into the text of the actual question.

Comment: Have edited the question

Comment: Your edits have substantially improved the question. However I have reinstated some important information that was lost along the way.